# Calculated column based on 2 other columns

Tags: calculated-column

I want to create a calculated column that evaluates the conditions of 2 other columns to decide on a response.

Column A
Column B
Column C

So if Column A=aaa and if Column B=bbb then Column C should display 12345.  I have several combinations I'll need to nest, which I think I can do if I can figure out the initial formula.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF([Column A]="aaa",(IF([Column B]="bbb","12345","It's not good!")),"It's not good!")
```

You can test SharePoint calculated columns in Excel by substituting the column names for cells.

I tested this on a list and had successful results. Column A & B are both Single lines of text with C being the calculated column. Are you getting an error message or incorrect results?

[image: Example of Columns]

Comment: I just tried that and unfortunately it didn't work.  This one is frustating. I've tried so many combos!

Comment: I got it to work!  Now I have to work on the nesting. Thank you!!